# Error while importing Springboot 2.7 projects in intellij Idea with maven 3.8.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

when Using start.spring.io
projects generated with springboot 2.7 comes with MavenProject 3.8.5 which when imported in intellij causes an error that is quite difficult to debug or not self speaking by itself.

The error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.model.validation.DefaultModelValidator: method 'void <init>()' not found
  at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.embedder.CustomModelValidator.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.embedder.CustomModelValidator
  at ClassRealm[maven.ext, parent: ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.model.validation.ModelValidator annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value="ide")

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.model.validation.ModelValidator
  roleHint: ide
```

Comment: What the version of IntelliJ IDEA? That should have been fixed in 2022.1 in the scope of [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290419/Maven-385-NoSuchMethodError-orgapachemavenmodelvalidationDefaultModelValidator-method-void-init-not-found)

Comment: Please show the pom file for that project..also more log output of that error ... Check to build on plain command line... not inside of IDEA..

Comment: was running a version 2021.2  updated and fixed the issue @KonstantinAnnikov thank you

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That should have been fixed in 2022.1 in the scope of [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290419/Maven-385-NoSuchMethodError-orgapachemavenmodelvalidationDefaultModelValidator-method-void-init-not-found)

Please update your IDE

Comment: this cost me a whole day, thx for the answer

Comment: Yes, This issue can be fixed by Upgrading to latest Intellij Version

Answer (score 43):

Under Intellij **File** > **Setting** > **Build Execution...** > **Build tools** > **Maven** > **Maven home path** just point to your maven directory:
[image]

Apply and reload project.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Nothing else works

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me - thank you! I tried a dozen of other tricks like Maven - Reload, and rebuild, etc - not nothing worked.

Comment: in my case i selected the "Bundled (Maven 3)" and it worked fine.

Comment: I did the same of @Dushan and it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error with stack: IDEA 2019.3, Maven 3.8.6, JDK 1.8.
So, problem was resolved by change Maven to version 3.6.1

Comment: I can confirm that changing Maven to version (in my case) 3.8.1 works with Spring Boot 2.7 as well.

Comment: Worked for me after i changed maven home path to 3.6.3

Answer (score 3):

I've just ran into this problem 20mins ago with my friend's project. The solution is just perfect.
If you don't want to update your IDE (for any reason) or downgrade yor Maven version, you just need to change your Maven Home path: (File | Settings | Build,...etc. | Build Tools | Maven) for any listed variant except "...wrapper".
Generally, I use separated maven in C:/my-maven-folder/...wrapper, so I've never had such a problem. Hope it helps!